# how to pass url in httptarget method while using PACT

Tags: java, testing, junit, pact, contract

while creating pact verification test i am using httpTarget Method. but the problem is my service dont have a port value. how can we run this? please advise.
Service URL=http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/iso3code/IND

below is my verification test.
package se.ff.bsv;

```
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.PactRunner;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.Provider;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.State;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.loader.PactFolder;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.loader.PactUrl;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.target.HttpTarget;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.target.Target;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.target.TestTarget;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.ClassRule;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Map;

@RunWith(PactRunner.class) // Say JUnit to run tests with custom Runner
@Provider("getCountryService") // Set up name of tested provider
@PactFolder("../pacts") // Point where to find pacts (See also section Pacts source in documentation)

//@PactUrl(urls = {"http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/iso3code/IND"} )

public class getCountryContractTest {

    @State("There is a country with alpha2_code as IN having name as India") // Method will be run before testing
                                                                                // interactions that require "with-data"
                                                                                // state
    public void hammerSmith() {
        System.out.println("There is a country with alpha2_code as IN having name as India");
    }

    @TestTarget // Annotation denotes Target that will be used for tests

    //public final Target target = new HttpTarget(8111);// Out-of-the-box implementation of Target (for more information take a look at Test Target section)
    public final Target target = new HttpTarget("http", "services.groupkt.com",);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't say your service don't have a port, but you can say your service uses a default port (for instance). In that case, try to use port 80.

Comment: i tried using 80 as port but service throws 404.   @TestTarget
 public final Target target= new HttpTarget("http", "services.groupkt.com", 80, "/country/get/iso3code/IND");

Comment: It worked with the below code. Thank you.public final Target target= new HttpTarget("http", "services.groupkt.com", 80, "");

Comment: You welcome.. please vote my post with V and give +1 if you can :-)